# Generating function of 'monotonic' partitions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

What is the generating function of partitions of $n$ into $a_1, \ldots, a_r$ where $a_1 \le  \ldots \le a_r$, $a_1 = 1$ and $a_i - a_{i-1} \le 1$ for $2 \le i \le r$?

Hint: find a bijection between set of these partitions and some set of partitions with a well-known generating function.

I've tried to find a bijection using Ferrers diagrams but with no result.

Comment: Is $a_i$  integer?

Comment: Yes, it is. I added tag 'discrete-mathematics' to the question.

Comment: What if you take into account how many times you use $1,$ then how many times you have $2,$ etc etc. i.e., $b_i = |\{j:a_j=i\}|,$ notice that $\sum i*b_i=n$

Comment: I moved my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317618/plain-integer-partitions-of-n-using-r-parts